# Write and read updated appSettings from config file during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, config

**Problem:**

I have a program where i write Keys+Values in my appconfig during runtime, but when i want to read them i get the old values and the only way to get the new values is by restarting the application.

As soon as i write the key+value programmically the config file is updated so that is not the problem, but i cannot figure out why i wont get the new values during the same runtime.

**I write like this:** *(tried with and without RefreshSection(key) - made no difference)*

```
public static void AddValue(string key, string value)
{
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(key);
}
```

**And i read it like this:**

```
string[] ItemsArray = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Items"].Split(',');
```

**Question:**

*How can i read the new keys (in runtime) which i added during the same runtime?*

Comment: Why use the AppSettings? UserSettings should be much easier to use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings

Comment: Be aware that [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Settings.Add appends value on each run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994302/configurationmanager-appsettings-settings-add-appends-value-on-each-run)

Comment: @Reniuz yes i know and that is fine :D + at Ranjith: well it suits my needs but thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Found an old post here
[Reloading configuration without restarting application using ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179254/reloading-configuration-without-restarting-application-using-configurationmanage)

Comment: i love you dude! So easy, jet something i googled an hour for, also on SO <3

Comment: happy to help :)